# media module update, shows always old version

Tags: 7, media, updating

I get a security update for some modules, I upgraded them with no problems,
but when come to media module, It shows me always the older version before the update run, although, I changed all files :

[image]

I checked also .info file to make sure that I downloaded the right new version :

```
name = Media
description = Provides the core Media API
package = Media
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = file_entity
dependencies[] = image
files[] = includes/MediaReadOnlyStreamWrapper.inc
files[] = test/media.types.test
files[] = test/media.entity.test
files[] = test/media.file.usage.test
configure = admin/config/media/browser

; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2014-01-08
version = "7.x-1.4"
core = "7.x"
project = "media"
datestamp = "1389219517"
```

Have anyone an idea about this strange happen!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one info file for this module in your module trees (all three of them)?

Comment: Yes, Im really 100% sure, and to be more certain, I grep for the word "7.x-1.3" in all media folder, I can't find anything related to this version.. Also I deleted all module files, and uploaded it again!!

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. There are three places where module can sit. `/modules`, `/sites/all/modules` and `/sites/default/modules` (or `/sites/example.com/modules` if you are not on default). And then module may be in every subfolder, at any depth. for example, accidentally inside another module's directory. Have you made sure second copy is not anywhere there?

Comment: yes, this is what give me find command : 
./sites/all/modules/devel/krumo/docs/media      ./sites/all/modules/ckeditor/plugins/media   ./sites/all/modules/media

Comment: can these folder names cause problems, I don't think so if they have not inside them a .info file !

Comment: So just inspect these places for media.info - and if there is one, with the version that "reappears", you found your offender. Edit: folder names themselves should not cause any harm.

Comment: There is one media.info file in the hole site...
Always surprises with web developement :)
anyway thanks a lot Molot, if I find something, i'll add the answer, if not I will not care a lot about this module :)